# Bug in "Related" and "Linked" questions

Tags: bug, voting, related-questions, linked-questions, sidebar

I was recently browsing questions on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf when I saw a little bug with the voting. When looking at the "Linked" and "Related" questions, I saw one that appeared in both, **but with different vote counts**. The image says it all.

[image: image of bug]

As you can see, the top and the bottom questions are the same but have different vote counts. Should something be done about this?

Comment: Probably just cache intervals for each list that don't quite line up with each other. Neither of those really reflect the most up-to-date scores anyways, and having that score be accurate and/or consistent between lists doesn't lead to anything actionable for a user, so, should be a non issue.